# Uncaught ReferenceError: oppstart is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

What do I have to do to define oppstart ? Is this the reason why the calculator isn't working ? I do not get any result when clicking calculate, however the rest of the code seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Vekt:
        <input type="text" id="txtVekt" />
        <br />
        <p>Hoyde:
            <input type="text" id="txtHoyde" />
        </p>
        <button id="btnBeregn">Beregn</button>
        <p id="resultat"></p>
        <script>
        window.onload = oppstart;

        function beregn() {
            var hoyde = document.getElementById("txtHoyde").value;
            var vekt = document.getElementById("txtVekt").value;

            var bmi = vekt / (hoyde * vekt);

            document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = "Din BMI er: " + bmi;
        }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace oppstart by beregn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>test</title>
      </head>
    <body>

    <p>Vekt: <input type="text" id="txtVekt" /><br />
    <p>Hoyde: <input type="text" id="txtHoyde" /></p>
      <button id="btnBeregn">Beregn</button>
      <p id="resultat"></p>

      <script>

      window.onload = beregn;

      function beregn () {
        var hoyde = document.getElementById("txtHoyde").value;
        var vekt = document.getElementById("txtVekt").value;

        var bmi = vekt / (hoyde * vekt);

        document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = "Din BMI er: " + bmi;
      }

    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That was helpful, but now the answer looks like this: Din BMI er: NaN. I expected a number.

Comment: that is because you executes beregn when you load the function, not when you actually set values in your inputs. at load your values are undefined so you have NaN.. Don't forget to mark the question as answered or vote up if that helped you ;)

Comment: I don`t know if this is the right question, but where should I write window.onload = beregn;, then?

Comment: actually you have to write much more. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event